# Why classes are not extending Object class in source code of Flutter framework?

Tags: flutter, dart, object, inheritance

Looking at the source code of the Flutter, I found out that no class extends the Object class explicitly. I know that, for Java, it is true that every class will be extending Object implicitly. Is it true for Dart also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

You can read more about it on [flutter.dev](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Object-class.html)

> The base class for all Dart objects except null.
>
> Because Object is a root of the non-nullable Dart class hierarchy, every other non-Null Dart class is a subclass of Object.
>
> When you define a class, you should consider overriding toString to return a string describing an instance of that class. You might also need to define hashCode and operator ==, as described in the Implementing map keys section of the library tour.